# Why don't I get hostname mismatch error on localhost?

Tags: security, ssl, https

If I have a valid signed SSL cert, I can see the CN (common name) attribute does not have localhost or the LAN IP - but I do not see an SSL error "ssl_error_bad_cert_domain" when I connect to `https://localhost.` Surprisingly,I have seen this error (only in some cases) even if I connect to the public IP instead of hostname.

Can someone please help me with a reasoning ? I wonder if DNS (or say hosts files) would tell this resolution to the browser !

Comment: Which browser are you testing with?

Comment: Firefox. Does it matter ? I guess every browser has this "issue" (for the lack of a better word)

Comment: Can you double check if you haven't permanently added an exception? This should be in Options -> Advanced -> Encryption -> View Certificates -> Servers. There might be a 'localhost' entry. Also check the certificate that the browser is seeing: click on the lock in the location bar and look into the certificate details.